# How to save a string to text in Windows form(c++)?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

So I am trying to save a string (that is stored in a String variable) into a text file... I have literally spent almost 2 hour looking this up and have not been able to find out why c++ is incapable of writing string variable into a text document.

What am I missing here?

```
private: System::Void SaveButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

String^ _String= "WHATTHEFUCK";
//So this works vvv
ofstream _SaveFile;
_SaveFile.open("SaveCFG.txt");
_SaveFile << "FUUUUCK";  //<<<<<<<<
_SaveFile.close();
//^^^

//But this does NOT work vvv
ofstream _SaveFile;
_SaveFile.open("SaveCFG.txt");
_SaveFile << _String;  //<<<<<<<<
_SaveFile.close();
//^^^

//Neither does this vvv
ofstream _SaveFile;
_SaveFile.open("SaveCFG.txt");
_SaveFile << "WTF" << _String<< endl; //<<<<<<<<
_SaveFile.close();
//^^^
```

}

Comment: What are you getting in your text file? Anything? 4-8 characters of garbage? I haven't worked in C/C++ in over a decade but is it possibly writing the pointer value to the file and not the actual string?

Comment: Thanks I tried a char pointer and it worked. I was using a String^, and had to convert it to a std::string, then convert it to a char*. I honestly don't understand the point of multiple different ways to write a string and have to convert them between each other, because one string doesn't know the other string is a string. I guess ill' just stick with c#.

Comment: But, if you use C++/CLI, why don't you use use the managed File class?

Answer (score 0):

Might be way off here, but assuming that you are writing the pointer and not the string. Don't have a C++ compiler, but you could try (if I remember correctly):

```
//But this does NOT work vvv
ofstream _SaveFile;
_SaveFile.open("SaveCFG.txt");
_SaveFile << *_String;  // or is it &_String;
_SaveFile.close();
//^^^
```

It looks like nowadays people use std::string instead though. Hope you find your answer.